# Deriving All Key Kinematic Equations

Tags: kinematics

I would like to know how to derive all the key kinematic equations, I currently know how to derive about 3 and would like help with the other two.

> $v_f = v_i+at$

This seems pretty simple as $at = ∆x$ and $v_f = v_i+∆x$

> $∆x = \frac{v_i+v_f}{2}t$

I know this is derived from $∆x = Vavg(t)$ (and Vavg = $\frac{v_i+v_f}{2}$)

> $∆x = v_it+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

This would be a further derivation of $∆x = \frac{v_i+v_f}{2}t$ as $v_f = v_i+at$ so $∆x = \frac{v_i+v_f}{2}t$ would be $∆x = \frac{v_i+v_i+at}{2}t$ which can be simplified to $∆x = \frac{1}{2}at^2$

> $∆x = v_ft-\frac{1}{2}at^2$ (this is unknown to me)

Would this also be connected to $∆x = \frac{v_i+v_f}{2}t$?

> $v_f^2=v_i^2+2a∆x$ (this is unkown to me)

I have no idea

P.S If possible, could you please try and keep the derivations calculus free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well done on understanding $3$ out of $5$. Firstly, your third equation implies your fourth because $$\Delta x = (v_f - at)t+\frac{1}{2}at^2=v_f-\frac{1}{2}at^2.$$ Secondly, $$v_f^2-v_i^2=(v_f-v_i)(v_f+v_i)=at\frac{2\Delta x}{t}=2a\Delta x,$$so $v_f^2=v_i^2+2a\Delta x$.

Comment: You can get the last formula from the Work-Energy Theorem. The difference between the kinetic energy of the object between its initial and final states is equal to the work done on the object, F*d = m*a*delta x.

Comment: @Mephistopheles There are any number of ways to do it. As per the OP's request, I avoided anything to do with calculus, which that theorem is in general (although the case at hand is much easier). But yes, it's worth observing the energetic interpretation of that formula: change in KE = line integral of force.